# postgres split string in sub words and check exist or not in other string

Tags: sql, arrays, string, postgresql

I use postgresql 11

I want to make and advanced search .

my goal is to check if all the words of my text exist in original text

this is the original text

```
"dumas, franshesco robert Ferrer Lombardy alive"
```

this is the possibility of search :

`"franshesco robert alive"`  return **ok**

`"franshesco robert Ferrer Viran"`  **not ok** because **Viran** not extist in the original text

`"dumas franshesco , robert"`  **ok**

`"alive dumas ! franshesco"`  **ok**

`"alive dumas ! suzan franshesco "` not ok because **suzan** not extist in the original text

so meaning when make the search first split the text using space and exclude special character like `(,!?.)`

then check if all of this words exist or not in the original text `"dumas, franshesco robert Ferrer Lombardy alive"`

for example  to search this `"alive dumas ! franshesco"`
in the original text `"dumas, franshesco robert Ferrer Lombardy alive"`

fist  split the text and exclude special character

so to have this words `alive` and `dumas` and `franshesco`

then check if all of this words exist or not in the original text .

I use this code :

```
select  string_to_array(regexp_replace('alive dumas ! franshesco',  '[^\w]+',' ','g'), ' ') as val_arr
```

in order to split string into words and remove special character

the result is `"{alive,dumas,franshesco}"`

now I want to find the way to check if all of this words exist or not in this string

`"dumas, franshesco robert Ferrer Lombardy alive"`

can someone help me to find the correct query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want all rows in the table whose text contains only words from your parameter string. You already have the logic to turn a string to an array of words, so we can build upon it ; [array containment operator `<@`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) comes handy here.

Assuming that phrases are stored under column `txt` in `mytable`:

```
select *
from mytable 
where  string_to_array(regexp_replace(txt,  '[^\w]+',' ','g'), ' ') ) 
    <@ string_to_array(regexp_replace('alive dumas ! franshesco',  '[^\w]+',' ','g'), ' ')
```